# Replace everything from string1 to string2 in file including newlines

Tags: bash, shell, substitution

I have a file with content like this:
<sub>(marked as js for better readability only, could be any plain text file)</sub>

```js
some text
/*%SKIP% line comment %SKIP%*/
some text
/*%SKIP%
block
comment
I could contain everything except the end sequence
%SKIP%*/
some text
```

Now I want to remove everything between `/*%SKIP%` and `%SKIP%*/`, so that the file contains:

```
some text
some text
some text
```

Whether blank lines resist in the resulting file or not is not that relevant, but preferably no blank lines remain at the locations where something got removed. I was able to archieve this for single lines with `sed`, but failed when it comes to multi line content.

I guess it shouldn't matter that much, but as a sidenote:
the "start" and "end" string are variable and stored in bash variables `open_tag=/*%SKIP%` and `close_tag=%SKIP%*/`.

Only limitation is to use tools which are commonly pre installed on most linux distributions, so `sed`, `awk`, `perl` and `grep` should all be fine.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If `/*%SKIP%` or `%SKIP%*/` could appear alone in the middle of a line or if `%SKIP%*/` could appear before `/*%SKIP%`  on a line or 2 `/*%SKIP%`s before the first `%SKIP%*/` or one without the other or anything else other than the sunny-day case in your current example then you should include all of those non-sunny-day cases in your sample input/output otherwise you're like to get an answer that doesn't work for some of them.

Comment: Such cases won't occur, otherwise I'd have included them in my example. It already covers the worst case scenario (multiline) the solution needs to cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `perl` one-liner:

```bash
 $ cat input.txt
some text
/*%SKIP% line comment %SKIP%*/
some text
/*%SKIP%
block
comment
I could contain everything except the end sequence
%SKIP%*/
some text
$ perl -0777 -pe 's{\R?/\*%SKIP%.*?%SKIP%\*/}{}sg' input.txt
some text
some text
some text
```

This reads the entire file at once (`-0777`, perl 5.36.0 and newer can use `-g` instead), and replaces every SKIP block (Optionally preceded by a linebreak; used to help prevent empty lines in the output) with an empty string. Using `.*?` does non-greedy matching so it doesn't match everything between the first `/*%SKIP%` and the last `%SKIP%*/`, and the `s` option allows `.` to match newlines (`g` means for every match like in `sed`).

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
$ awk '/\/\*%SKIP%/,/%SKIP%\*\//{next}1' file
some text
some text
some text
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and appropriate regex for the field separator. The `FS` is basically:

```
/*%SKIP%[^(%SKIP%*/)*]%SKIP%*/
```

ie. start marker, anything but the end marker, end marker:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    RS="^$" # slurp the file in, it is now a single big record
    FS="/\\*%SKIP%([^%]|%(%|S(%|K(%|I(%|P%(SKIP%)*(%|*%|S(%|K(%|I%)))))))*([^S%]|S([^K%]|K([^I%]|I([^P%]|P([^%]|%(SKIP%)*([^S%*]|*[^%/]|S([^K%]|K([^I%]|I([^P%]|P[^%]))))))))))*(%(%|S(%|K(%|I(%|P%(SKIP%)*(%|*%|S(%|K(%|I%)))))))*(S((K(IP?)?)?|KIP%(SKIP%)*(*|S(K(IP?)?)?)?))?)*%SKIP%\\*/"
    OFS=""  # set OFS to empty
}
{
    $1=$1   # rebuild the record ie. replace field separators
    print   # and output
}' file
```

Output:

```
some text

some text

some text
```

Empty lines are the newlines after the `%SKIP%*/`.

It may or may not be able to fix the regex to work on other awks. I tried a few, failed and lost patience. I was fooling around with the regex and `grep -z -v -o` but first the 2 latter switches do not co-operate well.